# Как имитировать нажатие кнопки без Selenium?

Tags: python, веб-программирование

Есть сайт tradeback.io,мне нужно оттуда спарсить нужные данные,но без авторизации это не возможно. Суть моей проблемы в том,что там можно авторизоваться через стим,но как это сделать не используя селениум? Я думал о пост запросе,но на этом сайте нельзя отправить простой пост запрос на авторизацию. в стиме же можно авторизоваться через пост запрос. У меня возникла мысль о том,что можно войти в стим,а после перейти по ссылке авторизации на этот tradeback и там уже нажать кнопку "войти",так как я уже авторизован в стиме,от меня не потребует логин и пароль,а всего нужно нажать на кнопку

Comment: Ссылка и наработки?..

Comment: ссылка есть,а наработок нет,так как я не знаю,как это сделать